# Password check before page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a webpage that asks the user for a password prompt before the page loads. Once the correct password is typed, the page will proceed to load. If the password typed is incorrect, it will keep asking the user for the password until they get it right. The webpage currently does not ask for a password and goes right to the page.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Password Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="password.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="passwordCheck()">
<h1>How'd you know the password?</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Password: ilikepie
function passwordCheck(){
var password = prompt("Please enter the password.");

if (password.value=="ilikepie"){
window.alert("Password correct!");
else{
while(password.value !="ilikepie"){
window.alert(password);}
```

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise and not designed to actually keep anyone out.

Comment: Well, you've hooked your JavaScript to `onload` so it will not run until *after* the page has loaded, because that's what you told it to do.  I think there are more serious problems as well.

Comment: The syntax errors don't help either. I would suggest laying out your javascript better by indenting blocks of code. Then you can understand better what it is actually doing.

Comment: erm, anyone that views the source of the page will know the password!

Comment: I love that you managed to write the password in the comment too... as it wasn't visible enough already

Comment: I think this is an exercise, and that keeping the password secret is not important.  I hope!

Comment: If someone wants to setup this use-case (show page on correct password) on a production server, it is better to add authentication to nginx or apache (or whatever server you have) config files instead of using JS if you don't want to have a backend server to authenticate. That way, your html will load only if the username and password you type is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a login page and a destination page.  The login page should prompt for the password and, when it is correct, change `window.location` to the real page.

```
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
    if (password==="ilikepie"){
        window.location="realpage.html";
    } else{
        while(password !=="ilikepie"){
            password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
        }
        window.location="realpage.html";
    }
}
window.onload=passwordCheck;
```

You could actually get rid of that first check and just use the while loop.  Doing that is, as we teachers say, left as an exercise.

*Do* pay attention to the comments about this not providing any security at all.  There are (at least) two reasons why this is not secure.  The first is that the password is visible to anyone who knows about "view source."  The second is that, once one knows the URL of `realpage.html` one can navigate to it directly, bypassing the password challenge.

I assume you are doing this as an exercise, and now that you have something that executes without error, you will learn from it.  The simplest effective password protocol for the web is [HTTP Basic Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).  When you've learned everything you can from this exercise, read about Basic Access Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of code above creates an infinite loop within the while loop due to the fact that the cancel condition of the dialog box is not checked. In order to avoid that one would need to change it as follows:

```
function passwordCheck(){
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
    if (password==="ilikepie"){
        window.location="realpage.html";
    } else if (password!='' && password!=null) {
        while(password !=="ilikepie"){
            password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
        }
        window.location="realpage.html";
    }
}
window.onload=passwordCheck;
```

Comment: Note that depending on your browser the "Cancel" button in the dialog box either returns an empty string of a null character.

Answer (score 0):

This will ask you the password only one time if its correct otherwise it will keep asking. this is recursive function.

```
window.onload=passwordCheck;
function passwordCheck()
{
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password.");
    if (password !== "bello")
    {
        passwordCheck();
    }
}
```