# Stop chat clients from causing server to work when page linked

Tags: php, apache, download

So I have a (potentially) unique issue, and I've not had any luck finding a solution.

I have a website I made, that when a certain path is hit a zip file is created and sent to the client. This is a unique zip file for a particular user - only to be used once.

The problem: If this link is sent over a 'smart' chat client - like most of them are now - the chat client hits the url provided, causing my server to do that work for nothing.

I originally assumed it would be a HEAD request, but comes in as a standard GET, with no other easily discernible attributes.

Comment: There probably isn't much you can do to try and differentiate between those requests. If you can not make it dependent on something like an existing user session (which none of those bots would have, but the user logged in to the page in their browser would), then you might need to use an intermediate page, and have a form on there that causes a POST request, and only let your server do the work then. Bots/scrapers usually don't make POST requests.

Comment: Excellent suggestions, thank you. After writing this question, the idea came to me to use a quick password check/redirect (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25953760/4765038) - which may be the way I go. Is there a way to initiate this type of interface straight from the server though?